# Facebook API Auto accept friend request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a web application that uses the Facebook API.
I would like to implement/create a method which is able to auto accept friend request of my own Facebook account.

Is this even possible and how to implement it in C#/ ASP.NET MVC?

Thank you in advance!

*I  alreay read the Facebook Developers documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/ but haven't been able to solve my 'problem'.

Comment: You can only do what Facebook allows you to do. If they don't have API to support it, then sorry but it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to send or approve friend requests.

There is the [Friends Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/) but it sounds like you want this to work without user interaction which is impossible.

If you find some way to do this, you should report it via Facebook's whitehat bug bounty program, as it indicates a bug on Facebook's side.